# componentDidMount() is rendered before render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my initial state, I set `loading: false`. In render method, my logic is when `state.loading` is true, display `Loading`, else display another thing. In my `componentDidMount` method, I change the state to `loading: true`.

Why does it show `Loading` in the browser though at initial state loading is set to false?

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
       loading: false,
       character: {}
     };
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1').then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        character: data
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.loading ? 'Loading' : this.state.character.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would expect the code to work correctly. You describe this as a problem, it's unclear what desirable behaviour should be.

Comment: `componentDidMount()` is called immediately after the first render call, so the text on the page changes instantly, in a fraction of a millisecond. It happens so fast that you can't see the initial state.

Comment: Why not set `loading:true` as default as you are going to do the async call every time anyway.

Comment: I misread your questions. As @estus have said your code is doing exactly what you want it to do, the only way around it would be to artificially introduce a delay as pointed out below.

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` cannot be called before `render`.

`componentDidMount` is called when a component is mounted, instantly after initial `render` call.

`this.setState({ loading: true })` is set on component mount, the result is instantly displayed.

Answer (score 1):

just add 500ms or 1000ms delay.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
      this.setState({loading: false});
 }.bind(this), 1000);
```